# Citation in thesis

Tags: thesis

My question is about giving references in my thesis.

When I give a literature of my study, I mostly used a type of reference which is given below:

In [1], abc et al, studied xxx. it was a bla bla bla study. They underlined that bla bla bla(a paragraph)

In [2], def et al, studided yyy. they claimed that bla bla bla (another paragraph)

I also paraphrased whatever I write, but my question is about plagiarism. Did I need to give another reference to end of each paragraph because I paraphrased them, and I didn't add my ideas etc?

In next two days, my thesis will be published, but I couldn't find a proper answer. I have already pressed my thesis but it hasn't been signed yet. So, it is ok to leave it as it is? Please help me :(

Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you think the problem might be. I don't understand the part "end of each paragraph"

Comment: OK. I think the answer of user student covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in papers, it is commonly done this way: you refer to an author and then describe in your own words. Bust such description is usually no more than 1-2 sentences. Here, you have a full paragraph of description. To be on the safe side, you can add at the middle and at the end of the paragraph to add  something like "Johnson and colleagues add [1], that ...", "Johnson and colleagues conclude [1], that ...". So everyone will see once again that it was a description.

Comment: You can also use "the paper" and such, rather than the author names.

Comment: I think it should not be a problem. But maybe better ask your supervisor? He/she should know the university regulations and any potential pitfalls.

Comment: I think you are fine and you should not worry. Good Luck!